# Query engine binary for current platform "debian-openssl-1.0.x" could not be found

Tags: docker, prisma-graphql

I need help on **Dockerize** my **Prisma + GraphQL**, I have tried many more options and tricks to resolve this issue but can not able to make it work.

*Seems like when I actually run the application without Dockerize application work perfectly like below*

[image]

But after Dockerize the App, it shows me an error like below

[image]

Can anyone help me out with this, I can not able to publish or Dockerize the app in local environment?

**Dockerfile**

```
# pull the official base image  
FROM node:10.11.0 
 
# set your working directory  
WORKDIR /api  

# install application dependencies  
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install --silent  

RUN npm install -g @prisma/cli

# add app  
COPY . ./  
 
# will start app  
CMD ["node", "src/index.js"]
```

Comment: GraphQL is a text-based query language; it doesn't transfer video files.  What request are you making, to what URL, and what response are you getting?  Is the application code relevant at all?  Prisma puts a GraphQL interface on a database; how are you running and connecting to the database?

Comment: Hello @DavidMaze, I am not transferring any video files. I have simply created 3 tables in postgresql and connect that database using prisma with latest version. The questionable thing is like its working while I am running the application from visual studio, retrieve data from database as well. you can see snapshot. but after dockerize i can not able to connect database, its show me error related to *debian-openssl-1.0.x*

Comment: I can't see any details.  It looks like you included the Dockerfile and two videos but not any of the request details.  These details generally need to be included as plain text (not a video or image) and in the question itself (not behind a link).

Comment: @DavidMaze its not video files, its an image and editor of graphQL API, basically play icon is tool's run button not video files. both are images. and related to request detail - you can view image, already shared the request query using GraphQL.

Comment: This page has some more information https://github.com/prisma/prisma-client-js/issues/616